# What does the word 'which' refer to?

Tags: sentence-construction

​In this following context, what does the word 'which' refer to?

Does it refer to the word 'Pali Buddhism'?

Does the word 'pages' refer to somethings from 'Pali Buddhism'?

How should I take this bold and italic sentence simply?

The context

> ***WE have so far gained some idea of the history and scope of that Pali Buddhism to a limited study of which these pages are confined.***
> We must now come to closer grips with those inductions and ideals in
> this Pali Buddhism, which will one day, despite the slenderly based
> criticism that would rob them of all originality, be considered as a
> positive contribution to the history of philosophy.

Source: "Buddhism" P. 48

:by MRS. RHYS DAVIDS

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a relative word like *which* or *who* represents a word inside a preposition phrase. When this happens, we can move the whole preposition phrase to the front of the relative clause, or we can just move the *wh*-word and leave the rest of the preposition phrase at the end of the clause:

- the elephant **which** she was sitting **on**
- the elephant **on which** she was sitting

In the Original Poster's (OP's) example, the word *which* is inside a preposition phrase, which is inside another preposition phrase:

- [of which]
- [to a limited study [of which]]

The author has decided to move the whole larger preposition phrase with the word *which*. This makes the sentence rather difficult to understand, and it would have to be said with a particular intonation to make it work in speech.

It would have been easier to understand this sentence if the author had just moved the word *which* on its own, and left the rest of the preposition phrases at the end of the relative clause!!! Consider:

- that Pali Buddhism which these pages are confined to a limited study of.

Here it is easier to see that the word *which* refers to *that Pali Buddhism*.

Comment: +1 Thank you, Mrs Rhys Davids, but when I want to see a contortionist, I'll go to the *Cirque de Soleil*.

Comment: The author appears to be going to great lengths to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition. Which is a shame because it renders the sentence nearly incomprehensible.

Comment: @nschneid Ah, of course, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

**Which** refers to the 'inductions and ideals' (it must be something plural because of the reference to *they* later in the sentence).

**These pages** means 'this book'. The author is saying that the book is a limited (short?) study of Buddhism, and she has so far talked about its history and scope.

Comment: I think the question is about the "which" in the first sentence.